# R add subtotals until next blank

Tags: r

I have data like this in a csv file:

```
Id A B
1  1 
2  1 1
3    1
4  1 1
5  1 
6  1 1
7    1
```

I would like to add up all the Ones until the next blank appears. Not the total sum of all Ones. Only "subtotals" until the next blank. So in the example above this would result:

```
A B
2 3
3 2
```

I tried it in Excel and could not find a solution. 
Thanks.

Update:

This is the code that you gave me and (kind of ) worked:

```
dat <- read.table("my.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, text= "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53")
x <-sapply(dat[, -1], function(x) na.omit(with(rle(x), lengths * values)))
```

And this is the output of head(x):

```
$X1
  [1]  2  3  8  2  5 13  4 25  2 24  5  9  8  2 20 24  5  3  1 16 10 15  2 15  3 15  1
 [28] 10  3  1 12  4 11  6  3  1 23 24  5  6  5  1  1  7 12  3  8  4  7  2  6  4  4  1
 [55]  1  1 24  5  3  2  4  9  3  5 22  1  3 10  6  1 14  3  6  6  8  3 13  2  7  3  2
 [82] 16 16  2  3  2 12  2  9 23  3  9  7  8  2  6  3 23 10  4 13  3  2  5  1  1  7 10
[109]  8  5  4  3  4  5  5  1  4 10  1 16 39  9  1  1  9  3  2 13  5  9  7  9  6  1  3
[136]  1  4 44 21  2 12  1 59  4  2  7  1  8  3 12 10 10  8 18  5  1  1 13 11  2  1 18
[163] 12 11  5  1  2  8  8  7  5  6  2  5 19  2 21  3  1 18  1  2  9 12 11  3  8  2  5
[190] 11  2  5 20  4 16  7 11  2 14 14 15  2  2  6 12  5 13  3  4  2  2  3  8 11 11 14
[217]  2  4  2  3  9  5  6  6  4 10  5  2  9 18 17  5  4  3  6  9 23  3 12  3  5  1 19
[244]  4  4 13 26  3  9 17  3  3  1  1  4 17 14  8  2  7  6  5 37  6  1  5  9 13  1  5
[271]  2 22
attr(,"na.action")
  [1]   1   3   5   7   9  11  13  15  17  18  20  22  24  26  28  30  32  34  36  38
 [21]  40  42  44  46  48  50  52  53  55  57  59  61  63  65  67  69  71  73  74  76
 [41]  78  80  82  83  85  87  89  91  93  95  97  99 101 103 105 107 108 110 112 113
 [61] 115 117 119 121 123 125 127 129 130 132 134 136 138 140 142 144 145 147 149 151
 [81] 152 154 156 158 160 162 164 166 168 170 172 174 176 178 180 182 184 186 188 190
[101] 192 194 196 198 200 202 203 205 207 209 211 213 215 217 219 221 223 225 227 229
[121] 230 232 234 236 238 240 242 244 246 248 250 252 254 256 258 260 261 263 265 267
[141] 269 271 273 274 275 277 279 281 283 284 286 288 290 292 293 295 297 299 301 303
[161] 305 307 309 311 313 315 317 319 321 323 325 327 329 331 333 334 336 338 340 342
[181] 344 346 348 349 351 353 355 357 359 361 363 365 367 368 370 372 374 376 378 380
[201] 382 384 386 388 390 392 394 396 398 400 402 403 405 407 409 411 412 414 416 418
[221] 420 422 424 426 428 430 431 433 434 436 438 440 442 444 446 448 450 452 454 456
[241] 458 459 461 463 465 467 469 471 473 475 477 479 481 483 485 487 489 491 493 495
[261] 497 499 501 503 505 507 509 511 512 514 516 518 520 522 524 526 527 529 531 532
[281] 534 536 537 539 541 543 545 547 549 551 553 555 556 558 560 562 564 566 568 570
[301] 572 574
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

Comment: what happends if the number of sequences of consecutives 1 are different in column A and B? The question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this (I filled in some NAs)

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="Id A B
1  1 NA
2  1 1
3  NA  1
4  1 1
5  1 NA
6  1 1
7  NA  1")

sapply(dat[, -1], function(x) na.omit(with(rle(x), lengths * values)))
#      A B
# [1,] 2 3
# [2,] 3 2
```

Edit

```
 d <- as.data.frame(sapply(dat[, -1], function(x) na.omit(with(rle(x), lengths * values))))

str(d)
plot(d)
```

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting. Seems to work. But I would like to save this in a format I can plot (or a table). Is this possible. Just the subtotal lists. I ran your code and it gives me what I think I want and then prints (attr(, "na.action") and then prints something that seems every second number and then prints attr(,"class") and always "omit". I only need the first part until (attr(, "na.action") I think.

Comment: @user413734 you can just coerced it to a data frame with `as.data.frame(...)` and you can plot, see edits

Comment: For some reason I always get an error "Error in data.frame...arguments imply differing number of rows:").

Comment: does the example here work for you? `dput` the data frame you're working with and add it to your question

Comment: I pasted as an update what you asked me. I assume everything until attr(,"na.action") is what I want. At least it looks like it.

Comment: `dput(dat)` would be more helpful

Comment: 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
    1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
...

Comment: that's not what the output of a `dput` call looks like

Comment: But this is what I got, obviously much longer and at the end I get the following (shortend the variable names): 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA)), .Names = c("X", 
"X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", 
"X11", "X12", "X13", "X14", "X15" ... , "X53"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2406L))

Comment: you can do a subset of it, like `dput(head(dat, 20))`

Comment: structure(list(X = 1:20, X1 = c(NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA), X2 = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, ...

Answer (score 0):

Read the csv file using `na.strings=""` to get `NA` values where the empty fields are and define the function `runs` using `rle` which computes the runs.  Finally `sapply` `runs` over the required columns and covnert to data.frame:

```
Lines <- '"Id","A","B"
"1",1,
"2",1,1
"3",,1
"4",1,1
"5",1,
"6",1,1
"7",,1'

DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, na.strings = "")

runs <- function(x) with(rle(x), lengths[!is.na(values)])
as.data.frame(sapply(DF[-1], runs))
```

giving:

```
  A B
1 2 3
2 3 2
```

Comment: I want to read in a csv with over 2000 rows and 53 variables. How do i import so it will work with your code ? DF <- read.table("my.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, text= "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53")

Comment: `DF <- read.csv("my.csv", na.strings = "")` assuming `my.csv` contains the data in csv format.

Comment: Same error: Error in data.frame(X1 = c(2L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 13L, 4L, 25L, 2L, 24L,  : arguments imply differing number of rows:

Comment: The code shown is self contained and does not produce any errors.  Copy it from the answer and paste it into your R session.  If you are getting errors there is something differrent about what you have than has been shown.